# Matplotlib, Scatterplot, zero value bubbles drawn on y-axis, no margin

Tags: python, matplotlib

anyone knows how to deal with the behaviour that the zero-bubbles are ligned up with the y-axis ?
Has anyone had this behaviour before ? Just give me some search keywords, so I can figure it out for myself.

Thanks

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGUUZ.png)

What did you try and what were you expecting?:
I searched the internet for hours but didn_t find a solution

Comment: Without code, and without an explanation of what exactly you want to change, your question is very hard to answer.  May you want to use `ax.scatter(...., clip_on=False)`? Or `ax.set_xlim(xmin=-10)`? Or  `ax.margins(x=0.05)`? Or ....?

Comment: Did you try to create a minimal reproducible example?  Did you try to describe exactly what you want to change? (plotting the dot half outside? changing the margins? ...?)

Comment: I use this syntax:  ax.set_xlim([0, 1000])
I changed it to: ax.set_xlim([-10, 1000])
Now I have padding to the left!

Comment: So, as you don't seem to want the padding, and do want the full dot, you could try removing the clipping by the axes: `ax.scatter(...., clip_on=False)`.   Please add a minimal reproducible example, and a full explanation of your requirements to your post, not just to the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, can't comment on my own thread :(
This site has awesome people, but the restrictions are terrible.
My problem is solved with

```
self.ax1.set_xlim([-10, 1010])
self.ax1.set_xticks([0,100, 200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000])
```